# Does Red Faction: Armageddon require Steam?

Tags: pc, steam

Seeing [Red Faction: Armageddon](http://store.steampowered.com/app/55110/) has Steamworks (Steam Achievements and VAC) but on no other distributors page I checked steam is being mentioned, I was wondering:

Does Red Faction: Armageddon require Steam? If I buy it somewhere else than Steam, will I be able to activate it on Steam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red Faction: Armageddon **requires** Steam.

I am not able to find an official statement but [users reported](http://www.redfaction.com/forums/topic/14011) that retail version installs Steam.
The same would happen for keys you buy from other digital delivery services.

If you buy a key you can activate it as described by this [QA](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/415/can-i-register-a-retail-boxed-copy-of-a-game-with-steam).

Comment: The game is not listed in the retail-key-activateable list linked to by the QA. https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-wusf-3601

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check it because for some reason I cannot access that page, at the moment. But I am sure they will add soon that game to the list of games that can be activated.

Comment: Yeah, hopefully. Sad how obfuscated this is.