# How can I add Civilization IV to my Steam account?

Tags: steam, civilization-4

I installed a copy of Civilization 4 that I have bought and when I installed it, it didn't ask for a serial. But in Steam, I can only see an option that requires you to add the serial number. I checked the box, manual, etc. but I didn't find any serial number. How can I add my Civilization 4 game to my steam account?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/415/can-i-register-a-retail-boxed-copy-of-a-game-with-steam

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not all games that are released through Steam support adding the version not bought through Steam to the Steam library.

[This is the up-to-date list of games that support registering them in Steam](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-wusf-3601). As you can see, it doesn't include Civilization IV.

However, remember you can still add the game as a "non-Steam" game. This gives you the benefit of the Steam overlay, but does not make the game auto-update and does not allow you to download the game from Steam.

Comment: The irony here being that Civilization V is a Steamworks games and can't be played without it.

Comment: @user2974 - Civilization V and Civilization IV are different games.  When Civilization IV was released the publisher might not have wanted to spend the resources.  Steamworks is also something recently added to Steam that might not have been a choice when Civilization IV was originally released.