# How do I get Steam to recognize a non-Steam game?

Tags: steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I register a retail boxed copy of a game with Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/415/can-i-register-a-retail-boxed-copy-of-a-game-with-steam)

Long story short, I purchased Uplink through Introversion's website, and not through Steam. Turns out that was a mistake, as I paid 3x the cost going through the developer's website, but I digress.

Uplink is available on Steam, but I don't want to have to purchase it again. I know that I can add a non-Steam game to my library. So, my question is this:

Is there any way to get the Steam version without having to buy the game again?

I ask, because I'm worried that if I switch computers, I'll lose the copy that I already I've already purchased outside of Steam.

Comment: You could always ask the developer for a Steam Key if you can prove you purchased through them. They may be feeling nice.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes I didn't realize there was another question. Sorry! I voted to close.

Comment: @Tristan No problem! We have many Steam questions and the search can be kind of dodgy.

Answer (score 5):

Some games will give you steam activation codes that can be used to get the steam version through steam.  [Here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-wusf-3601#which) is a list of games that support this.  Uplink does not seem to be in the list, so it appears you likely can't activate your copy with steam.